# Semaphore Algorithm Sync Trouble

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, semaphore

I am trying to understand how to synchronize some threads using semaphores with the given constraints  0,1,2 complete work whenever; 3 must wait for 0 and 1; 4 must wait for 1 and 2 before starting; 5 should wait for 0 and 2. I believe my implementation for waiting is correct however once I send the signals i get outputs with missing children. My question is what I am doing wrong with my synchronization implementation?
Expectations are something like:

```
Mother Begins Spawning Threads.

Mother Finishes Spawning Threads.

Child # 2 has completed its assignment.
Child # 0 has completed its assignment.
Child # 1 has completed its assignment.
Child # 5 has completed its assignment.
Child # 3 has completed its assignment.
Child # 4 has completed its assignment.
```

All children have now reported that they finished.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sched.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "sem.h"
#include <cstdlib>

#define THREAD_COUNT 6

using namespace std;

extern sim_semaphore create_sim_sem(int) ;
extern void wait_sem (sim_semaphore) ;
extern void signal_sem (sim_semaphore) ;

pthread_mutex_t stdoutLock ;


int thrds_finished ;

// global sync variables

sim_semaphore   support_ready[THREAD_COUNT] ;
sim_semaphore   finished ;



/* These are global variable to represent threads created
dynamically. */
pthread_t thr[THREAD_COUNT] ; 

/* This is included to facilitate adding random delays in the code
-- as a debugging aid. */
extern long random(void);  


int checking = 0 ;

/* A data type - a struct (class) with an int field to represent
a thread ID. */
struct threadIdType
{
int id ;
};


void init() 
{ 

if ( 0!=pthread_mutex_init(&stdoutLock, NULL) )
{  cout << "MUTEX INITIALIZATION FAILURE!" << endl ;
exit(-1) ;}

thrds_finished = 0 ;

finished = create_sim_sem(0) ;
int count ;
for (count = 0; count < THREAD_COUNT ; count++)
{
support_ready[count] = create_sim_sem(0) ;
}

/* This initializes a random number generator */ 
srandom(time((time_t *) 0));
}

void rand_delay(int max) 
{
int m_delay, j ;
m_delay = (int) random()%max ;
for (j=0; j<m_delay; j++) sched_yield();  
}

void childMessage (int ID)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
cout << "Child # " << ID 
<< " has completed its assignment.\n" ;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
}

void * child(void * idPtr) 
{

int me = ((threadIdType *) (idPtr))->id, temp ;



 rand_delay(100) ;

// wait constraints
switch(me)
{
case  0: break ; // thread 0 just 'goes'
case  1: break ; // thread 1 just 'goes'
case  2: break ; // thread 2 just 'goes'
case  3: wait_sem (support_ready[0]) ; 
       wait_sem (support_ready[1]) ;  // thread 3 waits for both 0 and 1
       break ;
case  4: wait_sem (support_ready[1]) ; 
       wait_sem (support_ready[2]) ;  // thread 4 waits for both 1 and 2
       break ;
case  5: wait_sem (support_ready[0]) ; 
       wait_sem (support_ready[2]) ;  // thread 5 waits for both 0 and 2
       break ;
 default: pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
      cout << "\n\nBAD VALUE TO CASE STATMENT!!\n\n" ;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
      exit (-1);  break ;
 }




 rand_delay(1000) ;

  /* Next increment thrds_finished - to keep track
     of how many child processes have finished their
     tasks. */

  /* Here put code you may need for protecting
     thrds_finished. */
/* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */


/* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */
     /* This code increments thrds_finished in a way
        that magnifies the problem if the critical section
        problem is not solved correctly.  Of course,
        do not change this part of the code. */
   temp = thrds_finished ;
   rand_delay(1000) ; 
   temp++ ;
   rand_delay(1000) ; 
   thrds_finished = temp ;

   /* Here put additional code you may need for protecting
     thrds_finished. */
   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */




   /* HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH */
   /* Announce completion of the assignment. */
   childMessage(me) ;  


   switch(me) 
   {
   case  0: signal_sem(support_ready[0]); 
       signal_sem(support_ready[0]);  // thread 0 signals for threads 3 5
       break ;
   case  1: signal_sem(support_ready[1]) ;  // thread 1 signals for 3 4
       signal_sem(support_ready[1]) ; 
   break ;
   case  2: signal_sem(support_ready[2]) ;  // thread 2 signals for 4 5
       signal_sem(support_ready[2]) ; 
   break;
  case  3: signal_sem(support_ready[me]) ;break;
  case  4: signal_sem(support_ready[me]) ;break;
  case  5: signal_sem (finished); break;   // thread 5 signals to the mother 
  default: pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
      cout << "\n\nBAD VALUE TO CASE STATMENT!!\n\n" ; 
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
      exit (-1);  break ;
  }



  pthread_exit ((void *)0) ;
  }


  // spawn child threads and waits for them to finish
  void mother() 
  { 
  int i; 


  threadIdType * idPtr ; 

  /* Create child threads numbered 1 through 8. */

 pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
 cout << "Mother Begins Spawning Threads.\n"   << endl ;
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;

 for (i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT ; i++) 
 {
 idPtr = new threadIdType ; /* allocate memory for struct */
 idPtr->id = i ;  /* records current index as the child's ID */



 if ( 0!=pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, child, (void *) idPtr) )
 {  pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ; /* 'error out' code here */
 cout << "THREAD CREATION FAILURE!" << endl ;
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
 exit(-1) ; }



 if (0!=pthread_detach(thr[i]))
 {  pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;/* 'error out' code here */
 cout << "THREAD DETACHMENT FAILURE!" << endl ;
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
 exit(-1) ;}
 }

 rand_delay(3000) ; /* Simulate whatever may delay the mother thread */

 pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
 cout << "Mother Finishes Spawning Threads.\n"   << endl ;
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;

 /* Some synchronization code is needed here to make the mother
 behave correctly - she is not supposed to exit until after
 all the children have finished their tasks. */

 wait_sem (finished) ;


 pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
 cout << "\nAll children have now reported that they finished.\n" ;
 cout << "The value of the thrds_finished counter is: " ;
 cout << thrds_finished << ".\n" ;
 if (thrds_finished != THREAD_COUNT)
 cout << "BAD COUNTER VALUE!! - Critical Section Problem Failure!!\n" ;
 cout << "Mother exiting ... \n\n" ;
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock) ;
 return ;
 }



int main() 
{ 

cout << "\nWelcome to The Child Thread Workplace!\n\n" ;

/* This calls the function that performs initializations. */
init(); 

/* Execute the mother() function */ 
mother();

return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: "I believe my implementation for waiting is correct however once I send the signals i get unreliable results"...

Comment: added more info